# How accurate is the getSpeed()

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have found the acceleration of the device using accelerometer . There is a method called getSpeed() which gives the speed of the device during its motion. I wanted to know how accurate is the value returned by that method.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Pooya - no.  The getSpeed() method mentioned here belongs to the Android Location class, which is fairly distinct from the intertial sensors.  However, the method is too general for the question to be answerable - the accuracy of the speed would depend on the provider it is coming from (GPS, etc)